# Modificar script funcional de python (json to xml)

Tags: python, json, xml, script, scripting

Quería saber si alguien sabría como modificar este script funcional en Python para que el xml salga con el formato que yo quiero.

Os dejo el script, el resultado, y como quiero que sea.
Muchas gracias

Es de mis primeras veces tocando python por lo tanto no tengo mucha idea de como va ni de como se podria hacer, tambien el codigo del script es un codigo de otra persona, no lo he hecho yo.

**El script:**

```
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class Converter(object):
    def __init__(self, to_convert):
        self._to_convert = to_convert

    def convert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class JsonToXML(Converter):
    def __init__(self, to_convert):
        # assert hasattr(to_convert, 'keys')
        super(JsonToXML, self).__init__(to_convert)

    def convert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Converts a dictionary to an XML ElementTree Element
        """
        if isinstance(self._to_convert, dict):
            keys = list(self._to_convert.keys())
            if len(keys) > 1:
                self._to_convert={'root': self._to_convert}
        elif isinstance(self._to_convert, list):
            self._to_convert={'root': self._to_convert}

        root_tag = list(self._to_convert.keys())[0]
        print(root_tag)
        root = ElementTree.Element(root_tag)
        self._convert(root, self._to_convert[root_tag])
        return root

    def _convert(self, parent, dictitem):
        # assert not isinstance(dictitem, type([]))  # type(dictitem) is not type([])

        if isinstance(dictitem, dict):
            for (tag, child) in dictitem.items():
                if str(tag) == '#text':
                    parent.text = str(child)
                    return
                if str(tag)[0] == '@':
                    parent.attrib[tag[1:]] = child
                elif isinstance(child, list):  # type(child) is type([]):
                    # iterate through the array and convert
                    for list_child in child:
                        elem = ElementTree.Element(tag)
                        parent.append(elem)
                        self._convert(elem, list_child)
                else:
                    elem = ElementTree.Element(tag)
                    parent.append(elem)
                    self._convert(elem, child)
        elif isinstance(dictitem, list):
            for list_child in dictitem:
                elem = ElementTree.Element('element')
                parent.append(elem)
                self._convert(elem, list_child)
        else:
            parent.text = str(dictitem)


source = json.loads(json_input)
result = JsonToXML(source).convert()
body = ElementTree.tostring(result,encoding='UTF-8',method='xml')
xml_output = str(body.decode())
```

**El codigo JSON:**

```
{
  "transaction" : "LstItmLanguages",
  "records" : [ {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "DE",
    "MDITDS" : "Stift"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "ES",
    "MDITDS" : "BULON"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "FR",
    "MDITDS" : "AXE"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "GB",
    "MDITDS" : "PIN4111142"
  }, {
    "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "IT",
    "MDITDS" : "ITLngTst"
  }, {
   "MDITNO" : "1101.22.08.12",
    "MDLNCD" : "NL",
    "MDITDS" : "Pentest"
  } ]
}
```

**El resultado:**

```
<root>
  <transaction>LstItmLanguages</transaction>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>DE</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>Stift</MDITDS>
  </records>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>ES</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>BULON</MDITDS>
  </records>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>FR</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>AXE</MDITDS>
  </records>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>GB</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>PIN4111142</MDITDS>
  </records>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>IT</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>ITLngTst</MDITDS>
  </records>
  <records>
    <MDITNO>1101.22.08.12</MDITNO>
    <MDLNCD>NL</MDLNCD>
    <MDITDS>Pentest</MDITDS>
  </records>
</root>
```

**El resultado deseado:**

```
<languages>
               <language>DE</language>
               <Description>Stift</Description>
</languages>
<languages>
               <language>ES</language>
               <Description>BULON</Description>
</languages>
```

TDLR: Quiero saber como modificar el script para que el resultado sea :records>languages y en vez de ser MDLNCD > language y en vez de MDITDS> description.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Los requerimientos no funcionales también van dentro de la pregunta :) No teníamos cómo saber que iba dentro de un ERP

Answer (score 0):

Está como muy "reinventando la rueda" ese código, ¿no crees? Teniendo las librerías json y xml debería ser mucho más... fácil. Y ya que no es tu código, bien podrías buscar y aprender un poco ya que se puede. Lo otro: tu xml deseado no tiene pinta de válido porque no tiene nodo raíz :)

La salida para que alguien lo lea y no estalle en llamas debería ser algo como

```
<root>
      <languages>
               <language>DE</language>
               <Description>Stift</Description>
      </languages>
      <languages>
               <language>ES</language>
               <Description>BULON</Description>
      </languages>
</root>
```

Hacer eso sería algo **parecido a** (revisa los comentarios, hay detalles faltantes para que revises):

```
import json as JS
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   
# Por si el json está en un archivo...
with open("fuente.json", "r") as json_file:
   
    # carga el json en una variable
    data = JS.load(json_file);
   
    # Tu root se llamará groot :)
    root = ET.Element("groot")
   
    # Por cada elemento en records, armas un language
    # (acá iteras sobre records (que está dentro de la variable data), busca cómo!)
           
           # Por cada uno, creas un nodo languages
           NuevoLanguages = ET.SubElement(root, "languages")

           # Dentro, pones el contenido de los valores deseados en nuevos nodos hijos
           NuevoLang = ET.SubElement(NuevoLanguages, "language").text(##valor_de_MDLNCD_en_iteración##)
           NuevoDescription = ET.SubElement(NuevoLanguages, "description").text(##valor_de_MDITDS_en_iteración##) 
   
    # Se arma el árbol de elementos a partir de lo que has añadido al elemento raíz
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
   
    # Salida a archivo
    tree.write("salida.xml")
```

Comment: Hola! El codigo esta asi ya que el script esta dentro de un ERP que tiene un apartado para creacion de scripts, por lo tanto no es python puro que puedas coger y usar librerias y extensiones, por ejemplo no se puede usar el open with ya que da error , el write tambien, de todas formas gracias por tu detallada explicacion, voy a ver si consigo sacar algo revisando a fondo el codigo que me has  dado. :)